# Trogan.GenericKD keeps appearing - worth wiping machine?

Tags: windows-10, virus, anti-virus, virus-removal

As the family tech support, I got a call when my folks started having some classic signs that they somehow got a virus. They have Sophos installed through a work program, but I guess it did not catch it. I had them install MalwareBytes and it found a decent list of stuff to kill. So that was done. It was still 'running slow', so I had them try Bitdefender. It found a different list. They ran it again, and it found more/repeated instances of the same thing - 'Trogan.GenericKD.2898920'.

I also have tried both Kaspersky's Virus Removal Tool and TDSSKiller, but neither found any threats.

From what I can tell at this point, 'Trogan.GenericKD.2898920' is the only thing that is appearing.

Windows security/anti-virus is not really my thing. At this point, it seems like they can just keep running and running and running BitDefender and it will find this thing, but it isn't stopping it.

Also, I don't know if it was related to the virus or just poor planning, but they have no system restore images to 'step back' into, so that is not an option.

Short of wiping the machine, anything else I should get them to try?

Comment: Have them look at the logs/reports and report back to where the files are that are being flagged and their names.

Comment: [How to remove Trojan.GenericKD virus (Removal Guide)](https://malwaretips.com/blogs/trojan-generickd-removal/)

Comment: @Tim - Most recent log had multiple instances of 'Trogan.GenericKD.2898920' - that was the only thing it found. They were all located in Windows/Temp/tmpXXXXXXX/tmpYYYYYYY

Comment: Have them download [Sophos' virus removal tool](https://www.sophos.com/en-us/products/free-tools/virus-removal-tool.aspx)  then perform a [clean boot](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929135)


Once they boot clean, have them run Sophos' tool, as well as malwarebytes.  After it has removed them, have them renable all the services the disabled, and have them restart. This may or may not get it clean enough. But its a start.

Comment: @Tim - I'll be doing this today. Will report back. Thanks

Comment: So running Malwarebytes on clean boot, it found a file located in the admin user's AppData/Local/Temp/ folders. It labeled the vendor as 'Tuto4PC' and the file was called predm.tmp. Additionally, when looking at the list of services in the System Config, I noticed 'Crypkey license' in the list. I tracked that down to Crypserv.eve in the System32 folder. That was the only thing in the list that I'm unsure about.